# Create dataframe with schema provided as JSON file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

How can I create a pyspark data frame with 2 JSON files?

- file1: this file has complete data
- file2: this file has only the schema of file1 data.

**file1**

```
{"RESIDENCY":"AUS","EFFDT":"01-01-1900","EFF_STATUS":"A","DESCR":"Australian Resident","DESCRSHORT":"Australian"}
```

**file2**

```
[{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"RESIDENCY","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"EFFDT","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"EFF_STATUS","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"DESCR","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"DESCRSHORT","nullable":true,"type":"string"}],"type":"struct"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to read, first, the schema file using Python `json.load`, then convert it to `DataType` using [`StructType.fromJson`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType.fromJson).

```
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

with open("/path/to/file2.json") as f:
    json_schema = json.load(f)

schema = StructType.fromJson(json_schema[0])
```

Now just pass that schema to DataFrame Reader:

```
df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("/path/to/file1.json")

df.show()

#+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+
#|RESIDENCY|     EFFDT|EFF_STATUS|              DESCR|DESCRSHORT|
#+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+
#|      AUS|01-01-1900|         A|Australian Resident|Australian|
#+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+
```

**EDIT:**

If the file containing the schema is located in GCS, you can use Spark or Hadoop API to get the file content. Here is an example using Spark:

```
file_content = spark.read.text("/path/to/file2.json").rdd.map(
    lambda r: " ".join([str(elt) for elt in r])
).reduce(
    lambda x, y: "\n".join([x, y])
)

json_schema = json.loads(file_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found GCSFS packages to access files in GCP Buckets:

```
pip install gcsfs

import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='your GCP project name')

with fs.open('path/toread/sample.json', 'rb') as f:
     json_schema=json.load(f)
```